# Background application not working 

Tags: android

I have an Android application in When application go in background and headphone remove from phone alarm start.All is fine on foreground,but when application go in background its not work.I wrote code on activity onPause() as below

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        try{
        super.onPause();
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                if (intent.hasExtra("state")) {
                    int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", 0);
                    if (isHeadPhoneAttached && state == 0) {
                        isHeadPhoneAttached = false;
                        if (isTriggered) {
                                 createNotification();
                                 initTimerCounter();
                                 makeToat();
                                 /*handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);*/
                                /*callTriggerActivity();*/
                                /*showDialog(Headphone_DIALOG);*/
                                    }
                    } else if (!isHeadPhoneAttached && state == 1) {
                        isHeadPhoneAttached = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG));
        /*createNotification();
        initTimerCounter() ;*/

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but it's not working.Please anybody give me some idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can't be sure if your application is running in the background so registering an BroadcastReceiver in the onPause method of an Activity is general bad practice.

You should use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) instead